# Promise.all does not await for enclosing new Promise()

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

I've been struggling for hours to understand what I'm doing wrong in the following:

This is a function that takes as an argument an array `exampleArr`:

```
const mapOverItemsArray= async (exampleArr) => {
    let resultObj= {};

    await Promise.all(exampleArr.map(async item=> {
        await timeout(1000);
        let result;
        try{
            const response = await axios.get(`...api/${item}`);
            result= processResponse(response)
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        };

        resultObj= {
            ...resultObj,
            [item]: result
        };
    })
    );
    return resultObj;
};
```

It is intended to await for a function `timeout`, that returns a promise , because the API has /second usage limits:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

But it does not seem to wait, which I can tell by the error messages - namely too many requests. Additionally, this is how I call the `mapOverItemsArray`:

```
//... enclosing async function
 await mapOverItemsArray(exampleArr);
 //...rest
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: 1) You should `return result` from the inner function, which means an array of results falls out of `await Promise.all(...)`, which you should *then* merge into one object if you want to. That would be easier to follow than manipulating an outer scope variable from inside a `map` callback. 2) All those promises will be executed at the same time, so they'll all wait 1 second, and then all make requests immediately. You'll want to chain all of them if you want for each request to wait for the previous one.

Comment: @deceze Thanks so much for the reply! I have addressed your first point, whereas the second one, do you mean something like `timeout(1000).then(async()=>{
                const response = await axios.get('....');
                ticker = extractTickerFromApiResponse(response)
            })`?

Comment: No. See the second duplicate above for how to create a mutually dependent chain of promises, instead of a parallel executing array of promises.